# How can I check so that if any elements relate to the if the foreach would set it instead of later going to the else?

Tags: c#

How can I check so that if any elements relate to the if the foreach would set it instead of later going to the else?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    Grass grass = new Grass(32 + 32 * i, 32 * 12);
    GrassList.Add(grass);
}

foreach (Grass grass in GrassList)
{
    if (grass.Rect.X - 32 <= Rect.X && grass.Rect.X + 32 >= Rect.X && grass.Rect.Y - 65 <= Rect.Y)
    {
        FallSpeed = 0;
        isTouchingGround = true;
    }
    else
    {
        FallSpeed = 3;
        isTouchingGround = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you know the code is not checking all the 3 elements in the list ?

Comment: The result are obvious when I compile the code, that's how I know.

Comment: in case you are basing your conclusions on the FINAL value of "isTouchingGround", don't forget that it will reflect the state of the last grass element in the list...

Comment: What do you mean with "when I compile the code" - you mean when you run your code ?

Comment: So if if is satisfied at first element from list you dont want to fall into else part for any other element for that you can use `break;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the LINQ expression with if condition to achieve what you want also

```
  FallSpeed = 3;
  isTouchingGround = false;

  if(GrassList.Any(
      grass => grass.Rect.X - 32 <= Rect.X &&
               grass.Rect.X + 32 >= Rect.X && 
               grass.Rect.Y - 65 <= Rect.Y))
  {
     FallSpeed = 0;
     isTouchingGround = true;
  }
```

Comment: LOL @ "lambada expression"

Comment: A future LINQ tip: Whenever you are doing `.Where(foo).Count()` you can move the predicate to `.Count(foo)` and it will work the same.

Comment: And you can use `.Any(foo)` instead of `.Count(foo) > 0` :) Anyway, I prefer this approach greatly to the `foreach` + `break` style, so good work!

Comment: And since you are checking for a `.Count(...) > 0`, you can simply use the `.Any(...)` extension method. Will even save a few cpu cycles, since it stops after the first item satisfies the condition.

Comment: Even better than the foreach + break!

Comment: @DarkDeSaint Check if you have included the `System.Linq`

Comment: If you do this a lot, LINQ will have a performance overhead compared to a simple loop.

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to short-circuit your evaluation. As soon as you know that you are touching the ground, `break` out of the loop. Your `else` branch is basically your default case.

```
FallSpeed = 3;
isTouchingGround = false;
foreach (Grass grass in GrassList)
{
    if (grass.Rect.X - 32 <= Rect.X && grass.Rect.X + 32 >= Rect.X && grass.Rect.Y - 65 <= Rect.Y)
    {
        FallSpeed = 0;
        isTouchingGround = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Just what I needed.